# Is there a method to initialize char array by user input, character after character?

Tags: arrays, c, input, char, initialization

In the following code, the first section inserts the user input into the array, However, the second section inserts automatically a null after the character input and takes the memory place of two characters(one for input and the second for null).

```
int numArray[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  printf("insert number %d:", (i + 1));
  scanf("%d", &numArray[i]);
}


char chArray[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  printf("insert character %d:", (i + 1));
  scanf("%c", &chArray[i]);
}
```

I am aware of the method of inserting the characters by string input for example (input: abcde) will insert the characters to the array, but I would love to hear if there is a method to get the input of a single character at a time and insert it into the array?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel You beat me to it ...

Comment: You can use `scanf` for this although is hard to get it right. Did you try `getchar()`? Just discard the newlines (`\n`).

Comment: "However, the second section inserts automatically a null" -- It is not a "null", but rather the newline character that you are reading, due to the ENTER key being pressed.